# How to search by a relationship with Searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

On my app I have a entity called Talent that can have many talent abilities. Like this:

```
#model/talent.rb
class Talent < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick
  has_many :talent_talent_abilities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :talent_abilities, through: :talent_talent_abilities
  scope :search_import, -> { includes(:talent_type, :talent_abilities, :talent_talent_abilities, :talent_primary_equipments, :talent_interests) }
```

So, for example, if I go on console and do a:

```
 t.talent_abilities = 
      TalentAbility Load (11.7ms)  SELECT  "talent_abilities".* FROM "talent_abilities" INNER JOIN "talent_talent_abilities" ON "talent_abilities"."id" = "talent_talent_abilities"."talent_ability_id" WHERE "talent_talent_abilities"."talent_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["talent_id", 13], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

I want that, on my searchkick I can search based on if the user has or not a talent ability. So, in this example, I want that if I put "Scuba diving" on my search, it return all the Talents that has a talent_ability.name of Scuba diving".

I added this method to my Talent model:

```
def search_data
    {
      name: user.full_name,
      gender: gender,
      ethnicity: ethnicity,
      eye_color: eye_color,
      hair_color: hair_color,
      type: talent_type&.name,
      talent_ability: talent_abilities.name
    }
```

But if I do a search with the word "Scuba" I dont get any results?

What Im doing wrong here? This is the right way to add a relationship on a searchkick search?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked what `talent_abilities.name` return. I think if you try calling it from rails console it will throw an error like `undefined method`name' for `#<Property::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` as `talent_abilities` is actually a ActiveRecord Collection.

To solve this you could try something like this:

```
talent_ability: talent_abilities.pluck(:name).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this depends somewhat on how you plan to implement the search. If you are only performing a text query, then the approach mentioned by @mehedi will work, although I would also recommend adding the following to your search data:

```
talent_ability_names: talent_abilities.pluck(:name)
```

That way you'll have an array of names, meaning you can use the text query for other attributes and then filter by one or more abilities, e.g.

```
Talent.search(params[:query], where: {talent_ability_names: Array(params[:abilities])})
```

By combining this approach with the one suggested by @mehedi, you should get results both from a matching text query for the ability, and from a filter (if that's something you need).